# Recreating equation in R returns different value

Tags: r, numerics

I am trying to understand an equation that is used to determine sample size. To do this, I am re-creating the example from a [tutorial](https://servirglobal.net/Portals/0/Documents/Articles/ChangeDetectionTraining/Module3_LC_Classification_Accuracy_Assessment.pdf) in R. However, when I re-create the example in R I get a different value.

In the tutorial (see image below), the following is provided as an example: `(0.098/0.005)^2 = 387.`

When I recreate this example in R, I get the following value: `(0.098 / 0.005)^2 = 384.16.`

Have I made an error that leads to this different result?

Below is an image of the tutorial to provide context

[image]

```
# In the tutorial, the equations results in: n = (0.098/0.005)^2 = 387
# Yet in R, the result is n = 384.16. Have I made an error?

Wi =  c(16.3/100,  77.6/100,  4.69/100, 1.21/100,  0.10/100, 0.03/100)
    Si = c(0.099, 0.099, 0.000, 0.400, 0, 0)
    SP = 0.005 
    
    
    (round(sum(Wi * Si),3) / SP)^2
    
    (round(0.097801,3) / 0.005) ^ 2
```

Comment: The two values, 384 and 387, are *identical* relative to the imprecision of the statistic 0.098 used in their calculation.  Specifically, since "0.098" could be any value between 0.0975 and 0.0985, the result can be any value between 384.2 and 388.1.

Comment: I see. To confirm, I haven't made an error in my code? If so, I wonder if there any way to ensure the same values are produced when reproducing examples and equations from papers in R? My fear is that I will not be able to tell when my code results in a true error due to mistakes when reproducing an example in R, as opposed to when my code does not produce an error as the two values are identical relative to the imprecision of a number...

Comment: I've put (0.098 / 0.005)^2 into R, Google and Excel and they all return: n = 384.16. I wonder what the author of the paper did to return n =  387....it feels like you would need to go out of your way to not get 384.16, which is why I worry I've made a mistake.

Comment: The full calculation in `R`, namely `(((0.98 + c(-1,0,1)*0.005))/0.05)^2`, produces a range from 380.25 to 388.09.  To arrive at their number, the authors must have used a value that was close to 0.984 and rounded it to 0.98 for reporting purposes.  (This is a poor choice of rounding: you don't shouldn't round the inputs to your calculation to fewer places than you report the output.)

Comment: BTW, this is one of many good examples of why one should not attempt to learn statistics from documents that only incidentally use statistics.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. So to summarise, my value is (n = 384I is statistically sound and I have implemented the equation in R correctly, despite the difference in results from the document's n = 387.